# How to declare datarow outside foreach loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop, foreach, datarow

I am using foreach loop and inside that loop I declared datarow

```
DataSet ds = Business.Site.GetSiteActiveModulesWithStatus(siteId);               
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
```

How can I implement this datarow outside foreach loop and how can I use for loop instead of foreach loop?

Comment: I think you need a basic tutorial on C#, loops and generally control statements + ADO.NET. Come back if you have a precise question. Also I have no clue what is the current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop in a for:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    //To acess the row
    DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];
}
```

Outside the for, to acess a specific DataRow you can do like this:

```
//Change 0 to other numbers to acess other rows
DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the row variable outside of the loop, you simple have to declare it outside:

```
DataRow rowFound = null;

for(int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
     var currentRow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];

     if(true /*To do: define some matching criteria*/)
     {
         rowFound = currentRow;
     }
}

if(rowFound != null)
{
    // We found some matching, what shall we do?
}
```

But you could write the same also in a LINQish style:

```
var rowFound = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                           .Where(row => true /*To do: define some matching criteria*/)
                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

*All code in this answer is untested.*